# Google sheets Time Stamp "Matrix"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I am looking for solution how to create time stamps in google sheets but not only in one column and not in the same Tab. I need to get time everytime if user will populate any figure in the table with size 50 columns x 30 rows.

Example.

Figure populated in cell C5 Sheet1 = Timestamp in cell C5 Sheet2.

Figure populated in cell F15 Sheet1 = Timestamp in cell F15 Sheet2

At this moment I know how to create Time stamp but only for one column in the same Tab as Populated figure but it is not what exactly I need.
Much apreciated for any help or suggestion!

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Apps Script. It has a simple trigger `onEdit(e)` which can be used for that:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const { range, source: spreadsheet } = e

  // Do something only if Sheet1 is the one being edited
  if (range.getSheet().getName() === 'Sheet1') {
    // Get the exact same range but in Sheet2
    const timespampRange = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet2')
      .getRange(range.getRow(), range.getColumn(), range.getNumRows(), range.getNumColumns())

    // Set the current datetime to the Sheet2 range
    // The date is on the timezone GTM with the format 2021-03-17T13:03:17Z
    timespampRange.setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GTM', "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"))
  }
}
```

You will need to change the timezone to your own and the formatting (as I don't know what you want).

Note that you can add more conditionals on the `if` statement to add more restrictions (like the number of cells this triggers for).

You may change the names of the sheets but you'll also need to change them on the code. Also, you may protect the timestamp sheet.

### References

- [Utilities.formatDate(date, timeZone, format) (Google Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format)
- [onEdit(e) | Simple triggers (Google Apps Script guide)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)
- [Class Range (Google Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [Class Sheet (Google Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)
- [Class Spreadsheet (Google Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet)

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I did ask for. I forgot to write before that also I want make it works as it is but only on limited area on spreadsheet. Is it any chance to add it to existing code?  My requirement is for range I20:BF116. I promis to learn it myself ofor next projects :)

Comment: @HubertSkiba Do you even know JavaScript? If you have some experience with it this is a nice exercise. If you don't it might be too hard, but the best way of learning is by trying yourself! Give it a try and if you can't figure it out, ask another question. It doesn't seem to have been answered before, so I'd be better for future reference.

Comment: Here is where to start: What you are trying to do is to find the overlap between two rectangles (rectangles). Get the maximum of the top-left corner and the minimum of the bottom-right. Check that the result is actually a correct value and convert it back to a range. Here is a list of function you will need: Math.min(), Math.max(), Range.getRow(), Range.getColumn(), Range.getLastRow(), Range.getLastColumn() and Sheet.getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)

Comment: Thank You for advice Marti. To be honest with JavaScript I am just begginer. I just discovered that using scripts in my work is proper game changer. Curently I really want to learn it even in some online course which will be the best I think.

Comment: @HubertSkiba Nice! Also, the google-apps-script tag has [a nice list of resources](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) that may be useful to you ;)

Comment: Another big help from you Marti. There is nothing better than giving Fishing Rod instead of Fish. Realy apreciate that :) Thank you!